# send querystring to facebook app canvas

Tags: facebook, query-string

I am trying to create facebook app, and I do not know how to pass the querystring.

How do I pass a querystring parameter to facebook app?

I have added my url to canvas url in facebook app.

```
http://www.pollsdb.com/get.aspx?qtnid=1&width=239&headerhight=40&height=204
```

I want users to be able to access different polls by changing the `qtnid` in the querystring.

How should I do this?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query string you give in your canvas URL settings gets passed as it is.

If you want to link to your app from outside, you have to use the `app_data` parameter – everything you put in there gets passed to your app as well. If you need to transfer multiple values, JSON encode them before assigning them to `app_data` or something like that.